# What is the maximum length of an iOS video screen capture?

Tags: ios, screen-capture

I have been taking screen capture videos in iOS 11, but for some extended captures the recording stops and I don't get anything at all.

What is the maximum length of a screen capture video on an iOS device?

Tried on iPhone 7 and various iPads.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of articles online say there's no limit, but I think there is.

Whether you're recording on an iPhone, iPad or Mac, the only limit you'll encounter is the amount of space available on your device. I've done 4-5 hours of screen recording on iPad and Mac in the past and only had to stop because I'd finished recording what I wanted to record.

A screen capture can also stop if you lock your device or if something crashes. If that happens, the recording is still saved in Photos.

Unfortunately, there is no way to prove this with an official Apple article, but I think this is the most likely possibility.